# Store a String variable in Java to use it later

Tags: java, button, repository, preferences

I have a question. In my app I have a button, when I click on it a text is saved in a String variable, when the variable is not inside to action button the value is NULL, How can I make to save the value from the variable and use it later.

```
private void initialize() {
        frame = new JFrame();
        frame.setBounds(100, 100, 413, 445);
        frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
        frame.getContentPane().setLayout(null);

        JButton btnNewButton = new JButton("Word for Search");
        btnNewButton.setBounds(223, 62, 118, 23);
        frame.getContentPane().add(btnNewButton);

        textField = new JTextField();
        textField.setBounds(35, 63, 131, 20);
        frame.getContentPane().add(textField);
        textField.setColumns(10);


        btnNewButton.addActionListener( new ActionListener()
    {
        public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e)
        {
            search = textField.getText();
            System.out.println("String for car = " + search); 
        WebDriver driver = new FirefoxDriver();
        driver.get("https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/" + search);
        String tstr1 = driver.findElement(By.xpath("//*[@id='content']")).getText();
        System.out.println("String for car = " + tstr1);

        driver.close();
            }
        }); 

    }  
}
```

All I want is when I exit from `public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e)` the `String tstr1` keep the saved data.

Comment: Could you provide a running example, reduced to the necessary parts, to reproduce your problem and point out where the exact problem is?

Comment: I just updated the question.

Comment: you could simply create a class instance variable and save the String into it

Comment: How to do this, could you please tell me???? I'm coming from iOS and there is `NSUserDefaults` but in java i'm new. Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Define it outside of function as object member

```
    ...
    private String tstr1;
    ...
    private void initialize() {
        ...
        btnNewButton.addActionListener( new ActionListener() {
            public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
                ...
                tstr1 = driver.findElement(By.xpath("//*[@id='content']")).getText();
                ...
            }
        });
    }
```

Answer (score 2):

Not a very good practice but have you tried declaring your var as global?

This way your var can keep the value as long as you want.

```
private String globalString;

private void functions() {
   ...
}
```

Answer (score 1):

you can create a field in your class as

> `private String tstr1;`

and inside your method you can assign value

> `tstr1 = driver.findElement(By.xpath("//*[@id='content']")).getText();`

when you need to access the field, you can call

> tstr1;

Answer (score 1):

Exactly, all you need to do is to define a global variable. If you want to access the variable from outside the class you could simply add a Getter:

```
public String getTStr1() { return tstr1; }
```

If you have many Strings you want to save just use a List in a global way, e.g.,

```
private List<String> tStrings = new ArrayList<String>();
```

and add each tstr1 to the list

```
tStrings.add(tstr1);
```

Then you do not need a global tstr1 field.